# Linux bash script - Replace last occurrence of string in a file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, perl, sed

I have a XML file that looks something like this, and I only want to replace the last occurrence of /Shipment with /ShipHdr /ShipmentX:

```
<ShipmentX>
  <ShipHdr>
   <RefID>REF01</RefID>
   <HeaderReferenceNumber>1234565</HeaderReferenceNumber>
   <Shipment>
     <RefCode>GHIJK</RefCode>
     <ShipmentStatusCode>FG</ShipmentStatusCode>
   </Shipment>
   <Summary>
     <TotalWeight>10</TotalWeight>
   </Summary>
</Shipment>
```

Output:

```
<ShipmentX>
  <ShipHdr>
   <RefID>REF01</RefID>
   <HeaderReferenceNumber>1234565</HeaderReferenceNumber>
   <Shipment>
     <RefCode>GHIJK</RefCode>
     <ShipmentStatusCode>FG</ShipmentStatusCode>
   </Shipment>
   <Summary>
     <TotalWeight>10</TotalWeight>
   </Summary>
  </ShipHdr>
</ShipmentX>
```

Any advice on how I can do this using perl or sed in a bash script?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `perl -pe 's/<\/Shipment>\s*$/  <\/ShipHdr>\n<\/ShipmentX>/'`.

Comment: This does not produce the desired result because it also replaces the 1st occurrence of </Shipment> along with the last one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tac` and `awk`:

```
tac xml | awk '!p && /<\/Shipment>/{p=1;print "</ShipmentX>\n   </ShipHdr>"; next} 1'| tac
<ShipmentX>
  <ShipHdr>
   <RefID>REF01</RefID>
   <HeaderReferenceNumber>1234565</HeaderReferenceNumber>
   <Shipment>
     <RefCode>GHIJK</RefCode>
     <ShipmentStatusCode>FG</ShipmentStatusCode>
   </Shipment>
   <Summary>
     <TotalWeight>10</TotalWeight>
   </Summary>
   </ShipHdr>
</ShipmentX>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I just had to switch the ShipmentX and ShipHdr after the print command.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl the regex is `$n =~ s/(?s).*\K<\/Shipment>/<\/ShipHdr> <\/ShipmentX>/;`

Or, you can avoid the LTS with this syntax:

`$n =~ s{(?s).*\K</Shipment>}{</ShipHdr> </ShipmentX>};`

This regex finds only the *last* occurance of `</Shipment>`, no matter what comes after it, ie. there won't be another `</Shipment>` after it.

Comment: For some reason, I can't this to work. I tried `perl -pi -e "s{(?s).*\K</Shipment>}{</ShipHdr> </ShipmentX>}" $file`